# Searching an ArrayList for String Instance

Tags: java

I want to create  a code that allows you to put in a word then it searches through the `Arraylist`, then it sends that code with the new airport codes. I can't figure out how to search through the `ArrayList` and then print certain letters. One of my friend suggested `HashMap`, but it only wants me to put in integers for the letters.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Alphabet {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Put in a word, the machine will then translate it to airport codes!");
        String name = in.next();
        List<String> name1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        name1.add("Alpha");
        name1.add("Bravo");
        name1.add("Charlie");
        name1.add("Delta");
        name1.add("Echo");
        name1.add("Foxtrot");
        name1.add("Golf");
        name1.add("Hotel");
        name1.add("India");
        name1.add("Juliet");
        name1.add("Kilo");
        name1.add("Lima");
        name1.add("Mike");
        name1.add("November");
        name1.add("Oscar");
        name1.add("Papa");
        name1.add("Quebec");
        name1.add("Romeo");
        name1.add("Sierra");
        name1.add("Tango");
        name1.add("Uniform");
        name1.add("Victor");
        name1.add("Whiskey");
        name1.add("X-Ray");
        name1.add("Yankee");
        name1.add("Zulu");
        for (String string : name1) {
            if(name.equals(name1)){
                name1.equals(name1);
            }
        }
     System.out.println(name1);
    }

}
```

Comment: It should be `if(name.equals(string)`

Comment: on top of that, the second name1.equals(name1) really doesn't make any sense

Comment: Using a Map was a somewhat good advice (at least a good advice for making your code cleaner and easier to write), but you'd need to use an `HashMap<Character, String>` (or `HashMap<String,String>` if it's easier)

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense. You are looping a `name1` List but you are not using the iterated `string` value.

Answer (score 0):

That was a simple mistake, you are iterating the list but you did not take the string value to check with your name

```
for (String string: name1) {
            if(name.equals(string)){
                //Your code
            }
        }
```

You can use the following code as well.

```
name1.forEach(string -> {
            if (string.equals(name)) {
                System.out.println("found");
            } else System.out.println("Not found");
        });
```